# need to copy folder with sub folder without answering prompt

Tags: windows, batch

I need to copy folder A to folder B and folder A is having subfolders. I have tried xcopy and copy both are stuck.

```
C:\Users>xcopy  sushantg\A\* sushantg\B /s /e /h /T
Does sushantg\B specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
Does sushantg\B specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

Comment: Try `xcopy sushantg\A\*.* sushantg\B\*.* /s /e /h /T`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two main options here:

The first option is to add the `/i` parameter. The related text in the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) is as follows:

> If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination does not exist, xcopy assumes Destination specifies a directory name and creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files into the new directory. By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether Destination is a file or a directory.

Another option is to specify that the destination is a directory by ending it with a backslash, which would make the code look like this:

```
xcopy  sushantg\A\* sushantg\B\ /s /e /h /T
```

(Note the trailing backslash after the `B`)

I can't find any relevant documentation for this option at the moment, but I tested it locally and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem and adding a trailing backslash to the destination folder (your second option) fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo f | Xcopy /f /y sushantg\A\* sushantg\B /E /H
```