# writting a simple code to back up a file?

Tags: command-line

I am a complete noob but i was able to find this which does what i want. Just backing up a single file with a .bat file.

```
: variables
set drive=D:\backup
SET dateNtime="%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,6%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%"
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y

echo ### Backing up your Sites directory...
%backupcmd% "d:\example\example.txt" "%drive%\%dateNtime%"

echo Backup Complete - Your Backup is located at %drive%
```

problem is, when i try to run it as .bat file, this alway alway prop up

```
D:\w10>set drive=D:\backup

D:\w10>SET dateNtime="31-01-2019_16-38"

D:\w10>set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y

D:\w10>echo ### Backing up your Sites directory...
### Backing up your Sites directory...

D:\w10>xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y "d:\example\example.txt" "D:\backup\"31-01-2019_16-38""
Does D:\backup\31-01-2019_16-38 specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

How do i make it automatically select D(or F)?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://superuser.com/questions/775586/need-to-copy-folder-with-sub-folder-without-answering-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need to copy folder with sub folder without answering prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/775586/need-to-copy-folder-with-sub-folder-without-answering-prompt)

Comment: I tried adding /i at the end of set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /k /y /i. but it doesnt copy anymore

Comment: Try adding a trailing backslash as described in second option in link above, i.e. `%backupcmd% "d:\example\example.txt" "%drive%\%dateNtime%\"`.  It worked for me. The option `/i` only works if you are copying more than one file.  See `xcopy /?` for more info on this.